# VSCode's code completion shows StrictMath over String

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Just like what I stated in the title:

[image: screenshot]

I am using latest VSCode and have installed Visual Studio Intellicode and Java Extension Pack. I have no idea where is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **IntelliSense** provides code suggestions and they're in alphabetical order by default. So does it in my project:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can create a user snippet for this.

- Go to `Settings > User Snippets > Java`
- Paste this config:

  ```json
  {
      "String": {
          "prefix": "Str",
          "body": [
              "String"
          ],
          "description": "Snippet for String"
      }
  }
  ```

Here is the result of the snippet:

[image: example of the snippet]